# Riak: how to enable KV indexing of buckets by default?

Tags: riak, riak-search

Riak docs have very good explanation of KV searching and indexing http://docs.basho.com/riak/1.2.1/cookbooks/Riak-Search---Indexing-and-Querying-Riak-KV-Data/ . It is recommended there to enable KV indexing for each bucket separately. So, you need to call a special command for each of your buckets.

I would like to make all buckets KV indexed by default. How to achieve that? Is it possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the [default bucket properties](http://riak-users.197444.n3.nabble.com/Re-setting-default-bucket-props-td762740.html), but I would advise against that since you might some day want an un-indexed bucket.

**Edit** Following up on this - Riak 1.4 will let you set the boolean `search` property, but Riak prior to 1.4 requires that the commit hooks be specified when enabling search on a bucket. If you truly need to index everything that you're saving into Riak, my only current suggestion would be to dump the data into SOLR/Lucene automatically rather than attempt to put some complex semantics around enabling Riak Search the first time an object is written into a bucket.